# Multivariate Normal Distribution Function Matrix multiplication behaving not as expected

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I've created a function that aims to generate a 2D Gaussian array, as per the equation:

[image: 2d_gaussian]

However, the peaks are split at the edges of the parameter space instead of where the mean is.

```
def Gauss_2D(x_grid, y_grid, mean=np.array((0, 0)), covariance_matrix=np.array([[1, 0], [0, 1]])):
    x=np.linspace(-3, 3, x_grid)-mean[0]
    y=np.linspace(-3, 3, y_grid)-mean[1]

    xy=np.vstack((x, y))
    inv_cov_matrix = np.linalg.inv(covariance_matrix)

    exponent = -0.5 * (xy.T @ inv_cov_matrix @ xy)
    z = (1 / (2 * np.pi * np.sqrt(np.linalg.det(covariance_matrix)))) * np.exp(exponent)

    return z
```

I would also like to mention that I do have a code that works, shown below for posterity's sake, I just cannot seem to understand why the code above doesn't work.

```
def Gauss2D(x_grid, y_grid, mean=(0, 0), covariance_matrix=[[1, 0], [0, 1]]):
    x = np.linspace(-3, 3, x_grid)
    y = np.linspace(-3, 3, y_grid)
    x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

    xy = np.column_stack((x.flatten(), y.flatten()))
    inv_cov_matrix = np.linalg.inv(covariance_matrix)
    
    exponent = -0.5 * np.sum((xy - mean) @ inv_cov_matrix * (xy - mean), axis=1)
    z = (1 / (2 * np.pi * np.sqrt(np.linalg.det(covariance_matrix)))) * np.exp(exponent)

    return z.reshape(rows, cols)
```

The output of

```
g2d= Gauss_2D(100, 100)
plt.imshow(g2d, cmap='viridis', extent=(-3, 3, -3, 3))
```

yields a Gaussian centered on the bottom left and top right corners instead of the mean location when using the first function.

Comment: You can use SciPy to generate 2D Gauss distribution with the [scipy.stats.multivariate_normal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html#scipy.stats.multivariate_normal) function.

Comment: I made an n-dimensional gaussian implementation in scikit-guess (a personal side-project) in [`skg.ngauss.model`](https://scikit-guess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/skg.ngauss.html#skg.ngauss.model)

Comment: Also, your function will crash if you try something like `Gauss_2D(100, 101)`

Answer (score 0):

A simple debugging session should reveal exactly what the issue is.

```
x = np.linspace(-3, 3, x_grid) - mean[0]
y = np.linspace(-3, 3, y_grid) - mean[1]
```

This creates two arrays, of size `x_grid` and `y_grid` respectively. For simplicity, let's set both sizes to 3, so the arrays become `-3, 0, 3` when `mean` is zero.

In the working version, you apply `meshgrid` to the arrays. This creates a grid of `x` and `y` values, each `y_grid`-by-`x_grid` in size. You then ravel (actually you use `.flatten`, but there's no reason to make a copy of the data: use `.ravel` instead) the 3x3 arrays and stack them together into a 9x2 array of coordinates. This is something that you can get meaningful results from. Notice that applying `meshgrid` means that `x_grid` and `y_grid` don't have to be the same size.

In the broken code, you just stack the original arrays together to get a 3x2 array of coordinates. This won't even work if `x_grid` and `y_grid` don't match. Also, you don't reshape your result into `y_grid`, `x_grid` (which is what you should use in the working code instead of the globals `rows` and `cols` by the way), because that obviously won't work on an array that's the square root of the necessary size.